# Почему экспортируются значения в csv файл по два раза? PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Почему-то при этом скрипте у меня вставляются значения дубликатом. То есть должно быть 6 строчек, а получается 12, так как каждая строка из БД дублируется. В чём проблема может быть?

```
public function Export(){
        try {
            $fields = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product`");
            $fields->execute();
            $file = fopen(__DIR__.'/items.csv', 'w');
            fputs($file, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // UTF-8
            foreach($fields as $item){
                fputcsv($file, $item, ';');
            }
            fclose($file);
            echo "Данные заполнены!";
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw "Данные не заполнены: ".$th->getMessage();
        }
  }
```

Вот видите повторяется на скрине [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте изменить запрос на `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM \`product\``, чтобы отфильтровать дубликаты.

Comment: Не сработало, тоже самое записывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию pdo возвращает каждую строку таблицы как массив и с числовыми и со строковыми ключами, это режим `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`.

Чтобы возвращались только ключи строковые - надо [выставить fetchMode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php#refsect1-pdostatement.setfetchmode-examples) в `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
$fields = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product`");
$fields->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$fields->execute();
// ...
```

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо большое. У меня до этого стоял FETCH_ASSOC как параметр вроде функции fopen(точно не помню), но я удалил это в прошлый раз.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` __никак__ не влияет на `fopen`. Если ответ помог разрешить проблему - отметь его зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score -1):

Причина может быть в том, что вы неправильно используете метод fputcsv, который предназначен для записи одной строки в файл. В вашем случае вы перебираете все строки из БД и записываете каждую из них с помощью fputcsv, что в результате приводит к тому, что каждая строка записывается дважды.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно отказаться от использования fputcsv в цикле и использовать функцию fputs или fwrite для записи в файл.

Например, чтобы записать все строки в файл с помощью fputs, вы можете сделать следующее:

```
$fields = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product`");
$fields->execute();
$file = fopen(__DIR__.'/items.csv', 'w');
fputs($file, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // UTF-8
while ($item = $fields->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  fputs($file, implode(';', $item) . "\n");
}
fclose($file);
```

Или с помощью fwrite:

```
$fields = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `product`");
$fields->execute();
$file = fopen(__DIR__.'/items.csv', 'w');
fwrite($file, "\xEF\xBB\
```